# WiFi connection randomly drops on 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on dual-boot with Windows 10. 
My laptop is a Samsung NP370E4K, Core i5, 1TB, fairly new.

I first installed Linux Mint on it, the wifi was always disconnecting, sometimes would reconnect automatically, sometimes it asks for a password. Someone suggested me to switch to Ubuntu, so I did, and the issue persisted. I've tried many solutions on many topics, but some are just too complicated for a begginer like me and none of them really worked. Whenever I need a stable connection I need to use Windows. I also tried searching for a network driver but couldn't find it for Linux.

Here's the report of `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 01
   serial: 98:83:89:60:50:07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-62-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.28 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:18 memory:f7000000-f707ffff memory:f7080000-f708ffff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 05
   serial: 24:f5:aa:f9:4e:22
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:43 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

Comment: I think Windows is locking your device via `fast boot` setup on Windows, disable that and see it it improves your connectivity.

Comment: Thanks, but it was already disabled.